# Change 'Sort by Position' text to 'Sort by New' Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, toolbar, product-sorting, i18n

This must/should be easily achieved...I am simply hoping to **change the 'Sort By Position' text to 'Sort by New'** in the Magento category list toolbar.

I have attempted to do this by creating the folder i18n, within my theme folder in the app/ and pub/ directories, and adding the translation in 'en_US.csv'.

This doesn't seem to have had any affect... can anyone please suggest how this is achieved?

Answer (score 3):

1. di.xml override Magento\Catalog\Model\Config.php

> app\code\[Vendor]\[Module]\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
            <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Config" />
        </config>
```

2. Create Config.php file

> app\code\[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Config.php

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model;

class Config extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
{

public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
{
    $options = ['position' => __('New')];
    foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
        /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute */
        $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
    }

    return $options;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks bro Sweety Masmiya !

Answer (score 1):

Well, since they're both English, I don't think that approach will work.

You need to make some changes to the source code.

In your module, in the file **module_dir/Model/Config.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Config extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
{
    /**
     * Retrieve Attributes Used for Sort by as array
     * key = code, value = name
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        $options = ['position' => __('New')];
        foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute */
            $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

And in your **di.xml** add the following line:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Config" />
```

Comment: Any registration file needed Jorge1o1 or is this all I need?

Comment: This should be fine as long as you already have a module. If you don't already have a module then you do need to create a module with [these files](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/module-file-structure.html#required-files)

Answer (score 1):

> Create plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="custom_sortby_text" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config" />
</type>
```

> config.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Config
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    $options
    ) {
        $options['position'] = __('New');
        return $options;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if by 2.4.6 this has become easier, or if this has always been this easy...

Now, you can simply open (or create):

```
<mage_root>/app/design/frontend/<Theme_Vendor>/<Theme_Child>/i18n/en_GB.csv
```

(or whatever language you're using)

and add:

```
Position,Whatever
```

So in the case of this question, it would be:

```
Position,New
```

In my case it is now:

```
Position,Recommended
```